# How to emit a message only once in a stream-stream KSQL join?

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

How to emit messages from a stream-stream KSQL join?
I have a stream-stream KSQL join and it joins from 6 streams. But currently there is a case where the 6 input streams can emit the same message several times. However i need to emit it from my stream-stream join only once.

I tried following this article https://developer.confluent.io/tutorials/finding-distinct-events/ksql.html  from top to bottom, but it did not work for me. The messages are not being emitted at all from the RAW_VALUES_CLICKS stream or DISTINCT_CLICKS even.